# Unable to write some symbols with java.awt.Robot in a Spanish Keyboard

Tags: java, awtrobot

Using java.awt.Robot class in Java with a Spanish Keyboard like that show in the image, I was unable to simulate the keyPress of the following symbols:

```
{
}
[
]
~
@
#
^
\
|
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Principal5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");

        sleep(2000);

        writeString("aAbBcC012345();{} -=_+\t\n[]:\",<.>~!@#$%^&*\\|\'/?¿ñ¡");
    }

    private static void writeString(String str) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        // Press keys using robot
        char car;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            car = str.charAt(i);
            try {
                // Check if the current character is a capital letter
                if (Character.isUpperCase(car)) {
                    // Press shift key
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    // Press the current character
                    robot.keyPress(Character.toUpperCase(car));
                    // Release shift key
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                } else if (Character.isLetter(car)) {
                    // else display the character as it is
                    robot.keyPress(Character.toUpperCase(car));
                } else {
                    symbolPress(car);
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("Exception for character " + car + " " + e1.getMessage());
            }

            // wait for 200ms
            sleep(200);
        }

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }

    private static void symbolPress(char car) throws Exception {
        switch (car) {
            case ';':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
                break;

            case '(':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_8);
                break;
            case ')':               
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_9);
                break;
                
            /*
            case '{':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);
                break;
            case '}':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_DEAD_CEDILLA);
                break;
            */
        
            case ' ':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                break;
            case '-':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                break;          
            case '=':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_0);
                break;
            case '_':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                break;
            case '+':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
                break;
            case '\t':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                break;
            case '\n':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                break;
            
            /*
            case '[':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
                break;
            case ']':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
                break;
            */
            
            case ':':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                break;
            case '"':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_2);
                break;              
            case ',':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
                break;          
            case '<':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_LESS);
                break;              
            case '.':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                break;
            case '>':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_LESS);
                break;
                
            case '0':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                break;
            case '1':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                break;
            case '2':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                break;
            case '3':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                break;
            case '4':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                break;
            case '5':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                break;
            case '6':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_6);
                break;
            case '7':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_7);
                break;
            case '8':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_8);
                break;
            case '9':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_9);
                break;
            
            /*
            case '~':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_4, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                break;
            case '@':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_2);
                break;
            case '#':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH, KeyEvent.VK_3);
                break;
            case '^':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
                break;              
            case '\\':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
                break;
            case '|':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
                break;              
            */
                
            case '!':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_1);
                break;
            case '¡':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_INVERTED_EXCLAMATION_MARK);
                break;

            case '$':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_4);
                break;
            case '%':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_5);
                break;                                          
            case '&':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_6);
                break;
            case '*':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
                break;
            case '\'':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
                break;          
            case '/':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_7);
                break;
            case '?':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
                break;
            case '¿':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_INVERTED_EXCLAMATION_MARK);
                break;

            /*
            case '`':
                doType(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);
                break;
            */
                
            default:
                System.out.println("Not cathegorized character " + car);
        }

    }

    private static void doType(int... keyCodes) throws Exception {
        doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
    }

    private static void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) throws Exception {
        if (length > 0) {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
            doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
        }
    }

    // Our custom sleep method
    public static void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // Se ignora
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: If I uncomment those parts I get Exceptions

Comment: yes, 'Invalid key code'

Comment: several kinds of treatments apart of actual showed in comments also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
'{' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 129
'}'
'[' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 128
']' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 521
'~' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 52
'@' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 50
'#' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 51
'^' KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, 128
'\'
'|' KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 49
```